# SwiftUI by add style on button, text stop showing on Xcode preview

Tags: swift, button, swiftui

I am trying to add style to the button but after adding style my text on button stops showing in XCode preview.

```
 Button {
            } label: {
              Text("qmshahzad@yahoo.com")
            }.buttonStyle(.borderedProminent).tint(  .primary)
```

I also try

```
Button {
        } label: {
          Text("qmshahzad@yahoo.com")
        }.buttonStyle(.borderedProminent).tint( .mint)
```

[image: please check screenshot]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is because of the email address, a link will be detected.
To achieve the desired behavior, add verbatim to your Text()

```
Button {
} label: {
    HStack() {
        Text(verbatim: "qmshahzad@yahoo.com")
    }
}.buttonStyle(.borderedProminent).tint(  .primary)
```

[image: link within text]